# CUDA array reduction to sum of elements. How to communicate answer from device to host and print?

Tags: c, arrays, cuda, sum, reduction

I am trying to reduce an array to the sum of its elements using CUDA. I am having trouble communicating the sum calculated in the device back to the host so that it can be printed out.

this is the output I get:

contents of Array:  33  36  27  15  43  35  36  42  49  21

Reduced sum of Array elements = 4204303

reduced sum is obviously wrong.

here is my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cuda.h>

#define N 10

__global__ void reduce(int *g_idata, int *g_odata);
void random_ints (int *a, int n);

int main( void ) {
    int a[N], b[N]; // copies of a, b, c
    int *dev_a, *dev_b; // device copies of a, b, c
    int size = N * sizeof( int ); // we need space for 512 integers

    // allocate device copies of a, b, c
    cudaMalloc( (void**)&dev_a, size );
    cudaMalloc( (void**)&dev_b, size );

    //a = (int *)malloc( size );
    //b = (int *)malloc( size );

    random_ints( a, N );

    printf("contents of Array: ");  
    for(int i =0; i<N; i++)
    {
        printf(" %d ", a[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    // copy inputs to device
    cudaMemcpy( dev_a, a, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice );
    cudaMemcpy( dev_b, b, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice );

    // launch dot() kernel with 1 block and N threads
    reduce<<< 1, N >>>( dev_a, dev_b);

    // copy device result back to host copy of c
    cudaMemcpy( b, dev_b, sizeof( int ) , cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost );



    printf("Reduced sum of Array elements = %d ", b[0]);


    //free( a );
    // free( b ); 


    cudaFree( dev_a );
    cudaFree( dev_b );

    return 0;
}


__global__ void reduce(int *g_idata, int *g_odata) {

    extern __shared__ int sdata[];

    // each thread loads one element from global to shared mem
    int i = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;

    sdata[threadIdx.x] = g_idata[i];

    __syncthreads();
    // do reduction in shared mem
    for (int s=1; s < blockDim.x; s *=2) 
    {
        int index = 2 * s * threadIdx.x;;

        if (index < blockDim.x)
        {
            sdata[index] += sdata[index + s];
        }
        __syncthreads();
    }

    // write result for this block to global mem
    if (threadIdx.x == 0) g_odata[blockIdx.x] = sdata[0];
}

// CPU function to generate a vector of random integers
void random_ints (int *a, int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        a[i] = rand() % 50; // random number between 0 and 49
}
```

Comment: You are missing an argument to the kernel launch, and as a result, the kernel is never running and you are simply printing out the contents unitiatilised device memory. If you added elementary error checking to you code or used cuda-memcheck on you program, you would already know this.

Comment: I tried your suggestion but the reduced sum is still printing out the same. any other possible problems with my code?

Comment: Try changing this:  `if (index < blockDim.x)` to this: `if (index+s < blockDim.x)`

Comment: I figured out my problem. I was using GeForce GTX 280 as my device. I ssh to a device GeForce GTX 480. Not sure what the difference is but now my code works perfect. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the amount of shared memory if you use `extern` shared memory. 
You have two solutions :

with

```
extern __shared__ int sdata[];

reduce<<< 1, N, N*sizeof(int) >>>( dev_a, dev_b);
```

with this parameter, set the size of shared memory to use in this kernel.
with

```
__shared__ int sdata[N];
```

with N a constant number of elements.